# S3 bucket policy error "Conditions do not apply to combination of actions and resources in statement"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to create a s3 bucket policy with action:
`"Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject", "s3:PutObjectAcl" ]`

and a condition as below
 `"Condition": { "StringLike": {"s3:x-amz-acl": " bucket-owner-full-control"}}`

But it throws the below error:
**Conditions do not apply to combination of actions and resources in statement**

1. What exactly is this error?
2. Can someone help me why is this error occurring
3. what will be the solution.

Actually tried to add the whole policy but was not able to do so.
Thanks

Comment: how to do this with python, cant figure it out.

Comment: @ChopLabalagun
By this you mean you want to add the bucket policy using python??

Comment: correct, like  this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746025/add-policy-to-bucket-with-a-condition/69750682#69750682

Answer (score 3):

According to the [S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html) the below is why you receive this error.

> The condition key s3:x-amz-acl that you can use to grant condition permission for the s3:PutObject permission defines behavior of the x-amz-acl request header that the PUT Object API supports.

Essentially this condition key is bound to `PutObject` only, therefore your condition could never be evaluated for `s3:GetObject` or `s3:PutObjectAcl`.

If both these actions should be supported too you will need to add these actions as an additional statement to the bucket policy without the condition attached.

Comment: Yes commenting out the condition does work as expected but manual kinda imply it but i guess ill have to use not use it :)