# Add policy to bucket with a condition

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk, bucket

I have no idea how to setup the conditions for this bucket resource policy, the condition line is the problem:

```
        iBucket.add_to_resource_policy(
        iam.PolicyStatement(
            actions=["s3:PutObject"],
            effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            resources=[iBucket.bucket_arn],
            #conditions=[ aws_stepfunctions.Condition.string_equals('s3:x-amz-acl','bucket-owner-full-control')],
            principals=[iam.ServicePrincipal(f"logs.{os.environ['CDK_DEFAULT_REGION']}.amazonaws.com")]
        )
    )
```

I have commented out the condition but i am looking for a way to make the condition work as i am clearly doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `conditions` argument is a python `dict`:

```
    iBucket.add_to_resource_policy(
    iam.PolicyStatement(
        actions=["s3:PutObject"],
        effect=iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        resources=[iBucket.bucket_arn],
        conditions=[{"StringEquals":  {"s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"}}],
        principals=[iam.ServicePrincipal(f"logs.{os.environ['CDK_DEFAULT_REGION']}.amazonaws.com")]
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but you missed the last "}"  which i place like this "]}]" but the code complains about the ":" after x-amz-acl please validate your answer.

Comment: I missed the nesting of another object... should be fixed now

Comment: interesting, I believe i tried that already,still i copy your line into my code and i still get the error:

Invalid Condition type : 0 (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicy; Request ID: 8VFN2J4NMK29N; S3 Extended Request
ID: G1VniRgISMG9qm7Hl1q0fdGnsOdABwTf14cbOJ/pdidspp8=; Proxy: null)

Comment: This is the IAM STATE CHANGE:
"0": {"StringEquals": {"s3:x-amz-acl": [  "bucket-owner-full-control" ]  }  }

Comment: Perhaps it's not a list? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#bucket-keys-in-amazon-s3-policies

Comment: that is what i tried first but i still get the same error. This is very strange something must be missing.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions argument is not a list.
Try declaring it as String instead of as a list.

```
iBucket.add_to_resource_policy(
iam.PolicyStatement(
    ...
    conditions={"StringEquals":  {"s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"}},
    ...
)
```

)